# How to connect flow charts with arrows starting from within a block?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to connect "boxes" in a flow chart, with arrows starting from inside the box. Doing so with "hard-coded" coordinates after trial and error seems very burdensome. Is there an efficient way to produce:

[image: original image]

Currently I have:

[image: current]

produced from this:

```
%% PREAMBLE %%
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!0, text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{smallblock} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!0, text width=9em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block] at (0, 0) (init) {};
    \node [block] at (-2, -1.5) (identify) {};
    \node [smallblock] at (-1.5, -3.5) (excellence) {};
    \node [block] at (3, -1.5) (pass) {};
    \node [block] at (3, -3.5) (fail) {};
    \draw[->] (-0.2, -1.5) -- +(0, 1.1) [above];
    \draw[->] (-0.2, -1.5) -- +(1, 0) [above];
    \draw[||||||->] (-2.2, -3.2) -- +(0, 1.2) [above];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Last, how can I have a little filled square as an arrow tail? (that is,  instead of `\draw[||||||->]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired figure you can obtain width:

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}
\tikzstyle{smallblock} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!0, text width=9em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2cm, auto,
     block/.style = {draw, fill=blue!0,%rounded corners, 
                     text width=12em, minimum height=2em, align=center},
smallblock/.style = {draw, fill=blue!0,%rounded corners,  
                     text width=9em, minimum height=2em, align=center},
      Line/.style = {{Square[length=4pt,width=4pt]}-%
                     {Straight Barb[length=4pt]},
                     shorten <=-2pt},
                        ]
\node[block] at (0,    0) (init)                {init};
\node[block] at (-2,-1.5) (identify)            {identify};
\node[smallblock] at (-1.5,-3.5) (excellence)   {excelence};
\node[block] at (3.5, -1.5) (pass)                {pass};
\node[block] at (3.5, -3.0) (fail)                {fail};
\draw[Line] (excellence.north -| identify) -- (identify);
\draw[Line] ([yshift=5pt] fail.west) -| (init);
\draw[Line] (init |- pass) -- (pass);
%
\draw[{Square[length=4pt,width=4pt]}-]%is square this necessary?
            ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=5pt] init |- fail) -- + (2pt,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]
but better look you will achieve if you placed blocks as proposed @Gonzalo Medina in his answer. In this cases the code is more simple and logical:

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

    \begin{document}
\tikzstyle{smallblock} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!0, text width=9em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     block/.style = {draw, fill=blue!0,%rounded corners, 
                     text width=12em, minimum height=2em, align=center},
smallblock/.style = {draw, fill=blue!0,%rounded corners,  
                     text width=9em, minimum height=2em, align=center},
      Line/.style = {{Square[length=4pt,width=4pt]}-%
                     {Straight Barb[length=4pt]},
                     shorten <=-2pt},
                        ]
\node[block] at (0,0) (init) {init};
\node[block,below left=1cm and 0.5cm of init.south] (iden) {identify};
\node[smallblock,
      below left=1cm and 0cm of iden.south east] (excel) {excelence};
\node[block,below right=1cm and 0.5cm of init.south] (pass) {pass};
\node[block,below=of pass] (fail) {fail};
\draw[Line] (excel.north -| iden) -- (iden);
\draw[Line] (fail.west) -| (init);
\draw[Line] (init |- pass) -- (pass);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  block/.style={
    rectangle, 
    draw, 
    fill=blue!0, 
    text width=12em, 
    text centered, 
    rounded corners, 
    minimum height=2em
   },
  smallblock/.style={
    rectangle, 
    draw, 
    fill=blue!0, 
    text width=9em, 
    text centered, 
    rounded corners, 
    minimum height=2em
  },
  arro/.style={{Square[]->}}
}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.2cm]
    \node [block] (init) {ini};
    \node [block,below=of init,anchor=east,xshift=-20pt] (identify) {iden};
    \node [smallblock,below=of identify.south east,anchor=east] (excellence) {exce};
    \node [block,below=of init,anchor=west,xshift=20pt] (pass) {pass};
    \node [block,below=of pass.south west,anchor=west] (fail) {fail};
    \draw[arro] (excellence.north) -- (excellence.north|-identify.south);
    \draw[arro] (fail.west) -| coordinate[near end] (aux) (init.south);
    \draw[arro] (aux|-pass.west) -- (pass.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Remarks,

- To place the nodes, use the features provided by the `positioning` library.
- You can access the anchors of the nodes to place the arrows. For a node called A you can say `A.north`, or `A.south west` or using angular anchors: `A.130`, `A.40`.
- Using the `arrows.meta` library you can produce the arrow you a re looking with `Square[]`.
- Change the old `\tikzset` syntax to the more appropriate `\tikzset` syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for the intuitive remarks. This is what I will use for my own use, but I chose the other answer because it exactly replicates the graph in question.